# http stream wrapper missing from php

Tags: php, compilation

I just compiled php 5.2.17 with Suhosin Patch 0.9.7 and find that the `http` stream wrapper is missing ... I only have `https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, data`. I have set `allow_url_fopen = On` but to  no avail ...

What is causing the `http` stream wrapper to get excluded ?

Comment: Did you restart your server after turning on allow_url_fopen()?

Comment: yes ... phpinfo() reports that it is On ... and also https is there and working ... only http is missing

Comment: This is most likely a missing `configure --with-` option, or maybe even a missing dependency. You'll have to go back and check the output minutely.

Comment: the only difference is that we added --with-curl=shared ... now, curl is http related ... is this a known problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the answer myself ... the problem was that our compile script had `--with-curlwrappers` which seems to be a [really bad idea](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=290180466652). Until now this had no ill effect since we failed to properly link the curl library ... but since we fixed that in the new compile things started to fail ... now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure suhosin to whitelist http wrapper

Comment: I can see `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist` in the suhosin documentation, but it seems to be empty also adding `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist=http` does not seem to have any effect whatsoever, it does not even get listed by phpinfo() ... :-(